# how to use search view with recycler view and sqlite?

Tags: android

I need to use filter in recycler adapter with sqlite for searching items on recycler view

i made filter in recycler adapter

```
 public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    DatabaseHelper helper=new DatabaseHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+ Verbs.BTable_Name+" WHERE "+Verbs.BCOL_1+" like '%"+charText+"%'";
    Brand.brandList.clear();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {

        do {

            for (BrandSandG wp : brandSandGListFull) {
                wp = new BrandSandG(c.getInt(0), c.getString(1));
                if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                    Brand.brandList.add(wp);
                }
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Search View

```
@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        adapter.filter(newText);

        return true;
    }
```

how to get filtered value like from data base and set on recycler view and it not set back recycler view

Comment: Once seach text matches ur object, then it added to List then the List will updated to recycler view.

Comment: @Navin Kumar i tried the but not working !!!!

Comment: You want to use TempArrayList to load matched object and then you should brandSandGListFull = TempArrayList;

Comment: @Navin Kumer  Can you show me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search text will pass to recyclerView by below code.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
        return true;
    }
```

Then RecyclerViewAdapter class should implements **Filterable**

```
public class DashboardRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

//constructor loads data to dataList
      DashboardRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Object> data,Context context)
     {
            this.context = context;
            this.dataList = data;   
            this.filteredDataList = new ArrayList<>(data.size());
            this.filteredDataList.addAll(dataList);
        }

    //override this method, it gets the SerchText and then compares with dataList
    @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                    ArrayList<Object> filteredDataList_temp = new ArrayList<>();
                    String charString = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();

                    if (charString.isEmpty() || charString.trim().length() == 0 ) {
                        filteredDataList_temp = dataList;
                    } else {
                        for (Object row : dataList) {
                            FoodDetail r = (FoodDetail) row;
                            if (foodName.contains(charString)) {
                                    filteredDataList_temp.add(row);

                                }
                            }
                        }


                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    filterResults.values = filteredDataList_temp;
                    return filterResults;
                }


               @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                    if (filteredDataList != null) {
                        filteredDataList.clear();
                        filteredDataList.addAll((ArrayList<Object>) results.values);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();   //once completed Then RecyclerView updated with only searched List
                    }

                }
            };

    }
```

Comment: how do i set alphabets preference while searching  i mean that if two value are like this abc and bmn and if we search b. then supposed to be show bmn first but it show abc first and then bmn.

Comment: It will show matching data in order of index value only. If bmn index is before abc it will show first on search.